# find the customer id who has event in sequence a-->b-->c-->d in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, gaps-and-islands

Event table :

```
customerid  eventname  eventtime
----------  ---------  ---------
         1  a          1:00:00
         1  b          1:05:00
         1  c          1:10:00
         1  d          1:15:00
         2  a          1:00:00
         2  c          1:10:00
         2  d          1:15:00
         2  f          1:20:00
         3  b          2:00:00
         3  d          2:20:00
```

find the customer id who has event in sequence a-->b-->c-->d in SQL
output should be customerid 1

Comment: Please tag the actual RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Many questions: (1) MySQL or Oracle? Or SQL Server? Make up your mind, then edit the tags to keep only the applicable one. (2) What is the data type of `eventtime`? For example, in Oracle there is no "time" data type, only "date" data type (which has both date and time components). In any case, 1:10:00 can be after 23:50:00 as well as before it (depending on date). (3) What is your database version? Different versions have different tools. (4) "In sequence" - does that also mean *consecutive*?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully in generic SQL using each event separately and defining the relations between them.

```
SELECT A.customerid
FROM Event A
JOIN Event B USING customerid
JOIN Event C USING customerid
JOIN Event D USING customerid
WHERE A.eventtime < B.eventtime AND A.eventname='a' AND
 B.eventtime < C.eventtime AND B.eventname='b' AND
 C.eventtime < D.eventtime AND C.eventname='c' AND
 D.eventname='d'
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution might be string aggregation. The actual syntax may vary across databases, but the idea is:

```
select customerid
from mytable
group by customerid
having string_agg(eventname, ',' order by eventtime) = 'a,b,c,d'
```

This would work in Postgres. In SQL Server, you would phrase the `having` clause as:

```
string_agg(eventname, ',') within group(order by eventtime) = 'a,b,c,d'
```

In Oracle:

```
having listagg(eventname, ',') within group(order by eventtime) = 'a,b,c,d'
```

In MySQL:

```
having group_concat(eventname order by eventtime) = 'a,b,c,d'
```

Answer (score 0):

In a more portable way, use OLAP or similar functions along a time series.

Works also if there is an additional 'e', or 'z' row, as long as 'a','b', 'c', 'd' work.

Vertica, for example:

```
WITH
input(customerid,eventname,eventtime) AS (
          SELECT 1,'a',TIME '1:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'b',TIME '1:05:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'c',TIME '1:10:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'d',TIME '1:15:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'a',TIME '1:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'c',TIME '1:10:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'d',TIME '1:15:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'f',TIME '1:20:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'b',TIME '2:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'d',TIME '2:20:00'
)
SELECT
  *
, event_name()
, pattern_id()
, match_id()
FROM input
MATCH(
  PARTITION BY customerid
  ORDER BY eventtime
  DEFINE
    is_a AS eventname='a'
  , is_b AS eventname='b'
  , is_c AS eventname='c'
  , is_d AS eventname='d'
  PATTERN p AS (is_a is_b is_c is_d)
);
-- out  customerid | eventname | eventtime | event_name | pattern_id | match_id 
-- out ------------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+----------
-- out           1 | a         | 01:00:00  | is_a       |          1 |        1
-- out           1 | b         | 01:05:00  | is_b       |          1 |        2
-- out           1 | c         | 01:10:00  | is_c       |          1 |        3
-- out           1 | d         | 01:15:00  | is_d       |          1 |        4
```

Then, you can group by the pattern_id you got and calculate duration or whatever you need.

Any OLAP function supporting DBMS:

```
WITH input(customerid,eventname,eventtime) AS (
          SELECT 1,'a',TIME '1:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'b',TIME '1:05:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'c',TIME '1:10:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'d',TIME '1:15:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'a',TIME '1:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'c',TIME '1:10:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'d',TIME '1:15:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'f',TIME '1:20:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'b',TIME '2:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'d',TIME '2:20:00'
)
,
neighbours AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , LEAD(eventname,1) OVER(PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY eventtime) AS event2
  , LEAD(eventname,2) OVER(PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY eventtime) AS event3
  , LEAD(eventname,3) OVER(PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY eventtime) AS event4
  FROM input
)
SELECT
  *
FROM neighbours
WHERE eventname='a'
  AND event2   ='b'
  AND event3   ='c'
  AND event4   ='d'
;
-- out  customerid | eventname | eventtime | event2 | event3 | event4 
-- out ------------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+--------
-- out           1 | a         | 01:00:00  | b      | c      | d
```